# How to setup ElasticSearch cluster with auto-scaling on Amazon EC2?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a great tutorial [elasticsearch on ec2](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109115804/http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/elasticsearch-on-ec2) about configuring ES on Amazon EC2. I studied it and applied all recommendations.

Now I have AMI and can run any number of nodes in the cluster from this AMI. Auto-discovery is configured and the nodes join the cluster as they really should.

The question is **How to configure cluster in way that I can automatically launch/terminate nodes depending on cluster load?**

For example I want to have only 1 node running when we don't have any load and 12 nodes running on peak load. But wait, if I terminate 11 nodes in cluster what would happen with shards and replicas? **How to make sure I don't lose any data in cluster if I terminate 11 nodes out of 12 nodes?**

I might want to configure [S3 Gateway](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/gateway/s3/) for this. But all the gateways except for local are deprecated.

There is an article in the manual about [shards allocation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/allocation/). May be I'm missing something very basic but I should admit I failed to figure out if it **is possible to configure one node to always hold all the shards copies**. My goal is to make sure that if this would be the only node running in the cluster we still don't lose any data.

The only solution I can imagine now is to configure index to have 12 shards and 12 replicas. Then when up to 12 nodes are launched every node would have copy of every shard. But I don't like this solution cause I would have to reconfigure cluster if I might want to have more then 12 nodes on peak load.

Comment: Maybe, you want to create a custom script in AWS Cloudwatch & use it for autoscaling!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Auto scaling doesn't make a lot of sense with ElasticSearch.

Shard moving and re-allocation is not a light process, especially if you have a lot of data. It stresses IO and network, and can degrade the performance of ElasticSearch badly. (If you want to limit the effect you should throttle cluster recovery using settings like cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance, indices.recovery.concurrent_streams, indices.recovery.max_size_per_sec . This will limit the impact but will also slow the re-balancing and recovery).

Also, if you care about your data you don't want to have only 1 node ever. You need your data to be replicated, so you will need at least 2 nodes (or more if you feel safer with a higher replication level).

Another thing to remember is that while you can change the number of replicas, you can't change the number of shards. This is configured when you create your index and cannot be changed (if you want more shards you need to create another index and reindex all your data). So your number of shards should take into account the data size and the cluster size, considering the higher number of nodes you want but also your minimal setup (can fewer nodes hold all the shards and serve the estimated traffic?).

So theoretically, if you want to have 2 nodes at low time and 12 nodes on peak, you can set your index to have 6 shards with 1 replica. So on low times you have 2 nodes that hold 6 shards each, and on peak you have 12 nodes that hold 1 shard each.

But again, I strongly suggest rethinking this and testing the impact of shard moving on your cluster performance.

Comment: The load on the cluster is changed greatly over the time. Some time we have 250 requests per second and during other 20 hours a day we have 0 (zero) requests. This is why we consider configuring auto scaling. I like your idea about having 2 servers all the time and the setup with 6 shards and 1 replica. We are still researching and testing. I plan to come with more test results soon. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: But wait, with 6 shards and 1 replica setup we are having issues. Because when all 12 nodes are running each node would have only one copy of every shard. When we stop 10 nodes we would end up with only 2 shards available. The other 4 shards would be lost. The main question is 'we want to handle 0 to 1000 requests per second and don't want to pay for the additional hardware cause 80% of time cluster would have no requests'. We don't want to pay for 10 servers doing nothing 20 hours a day. I'm not a slowpoke, I was just very tired yesterday to think about this ;)

Comment: The other trick here is when some shard replica is not allocated on any server we can not insert documents to the index. This is why we are dynamically changing number of replicas when we start/stop servers.

Comment: Well, you can set a higher number of replicas so you will have more copies on your full cluster, and they will not be assigned when you take nodes down. Then you will have to set some stuff to make ES ignore the missing replicas. For instance you need to add a consistency=one parameter to your index requests so it doesn't look for a quorum of replicas, and also the index.recovery.initial_shards setting to avoid looking for a quorum upon index recovery. I guess it's possible to do, I don't know how much recommended.

Comment: If you can't autoscale it and resizing it is an expensive operation that you want to generally avoid, then why the hell do they call it _elastic_ search?

Comment: It does scale and it does so in a simple way, but auto-scaling according to load usually does not really work when talking about a data layer. Scaling the data means moving lots of data around and you usually don't want to do it constantly. But when you do need to scale, elasticsearch allows to do it quite easily, so I don't think there's a real issue with the naming here.

Comment: Using a mechanical analogy, ElasticSearch would be rigid-elastic-plastic. It is rigid when you want do down-scale dynamically, elastic if you monotonically scale up, and plastic when the cluster reaches a limit, either because of outgrown cluster state (driven by a high number of shards coupled with a large number of fields) or by search queries which can bring down the cluster.

Comment: This aside, rather than using downscaling to save costs, I propose that we use T2 instances in AWS (especially the new larger instance sizes) to host ElasticSearch, so that during low times, credits will accumulate, and during high peak times, they will be used. This bypasses the auto-scaling/dynamic shard allocation problem, while yielding cost benefits.

Answer (score 12):

In cases where the elasticity of your application is driven by a variable query load you could setup ES nodes configured to not store any data (node.data = false, http.enabled = true) and then put them in for auto scaling. These nodes could offload all the HTTP and result conflation processing from your main data nodes (freeing them up for more indexing and searching).

Since these nodes wouldn't have shards allocated to them bringing them up and down dynamically shouldn't be a problem and the auto-discovery should allow them to join the cluster.

Comment: If I am doing this, will it increase the performance of my search query over the elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: @edparris any more info on this in the AWS OpenSearch intervening decade? Would be great to see a revised answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an alternative approach using aws elastic search service(it will cost little bit  more than normal ec2 elasticsearch).Write a simple script which continuously monitor the load (through api/cli)on the service and if the load goes beyond the threshold, programatically increase the nodes of your aws elasticsearch-service cluster.Here the advantage is aws will take care of the scaling(As per the documentation they are taking a snaphost and launching a completely new cluster).This will work for scale down also.

Regarding Auto-scaling approach there is some challenges like shard movement has an impact on the existing cluster, also we need to more vigilant while scaling down.You can find a good article on scaling down [here](https://blog.mapillary.com/tech/2017/01/12/scaling-down-an-elasticsearch-cluster.html) which I have tested.If you can do some kind of intelligent automation of the steps in the above link through some scripting(python, shell) or through automation tools like Ansible, then the scaling in/out is achievable.But again you need to start the scaling up well before the normal limits since the scale up  activities can have an impact on existing cluster.

**Question:** is possible to configure one node to always hold all the shards copies?

**Answer:** Yes,its possible by explicit shard routing.More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a concern in general when it comes to employing auto-scalable architecture to meet temporary demands, but data still needs to be saved. I think there is a solution that leverages EBS

- map shards to specific EBS volumes. Lets say we need 15 shards. We will need 15 EBS Volumes
- amazon allows you to mount multiple volumes, so when we start we can start with few instances that have multiple volumes attached to them
- as load increase, we can spin up additional instance - upto 15.

The above solution is only advised if you know your max capacity requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I would be tempted to suggest solving this a different way in AWS. *I dont know what ES data this is or how its updated etc...* Making a lot of assumptions I would put the ES instance behind a ALB (app load balancer) I would have a scheduled process that creates updated AMI's regularly (if you do it often then it will be quick to do), then based on load of your single server I would trigger more instances to be created from the latest instance you have available. Add the new instances to the ALB to share some of the load. As this quiet down I would trigger the termination of the temp instances. If you go this route here are a couple more things to consider

- Use spot instances since they are cheaper and if it fits your use case
- The "T" instances dont fit well here since they need time to build up credits
- Use lambdas for the task of turning things on and off, if you want to be fancy you can trigger it based on a webhook to the aws gateway
- Making more assumptions about your use case, consider putting a Varnish server in front of your ES machine so that you can more cheaply provide scale based on a cache strategy (lots of assumptions here) based on the stress you can dial in the right TTL for cache eviction. Check out the soft-purge feature for our ES stuff we have gotten a lot of good value from this.
- if you do any of what i suggest here make sure to make your spawned ES instances report any logs back to a central addressable place on the persistent ES machine so you don't lose logs when the machines die